# Repo Setup for Hexo?

Tags: github-pages, hexo

I'm finally getting around to migrating my blog to some markdown goodness and hexo seemed to be the best option for me. I seem to be missing something about the workflow from hexo project to github pages though.

Should the hexo project live in one repo and then publish the generated content to a separate pages repo? Or is there some other mechanism (like branching) that should be used?

The former seems to be the most likely but I thought I'd ask first. Sorry if it seem s obvious, I may have confused myself reading about jekyll etc earlier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending of the type or site your deploying : `user/organization` or `project`, your code must be respectively pushed in `master` or `gh-pages` branch ([see gh page doc here](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)).

`http://flukus.github.io/` -> `master`

`http://flukus.github.io/myproject` -> `gh-pages`

Setup you github configuration (or other hoster) in you `_config.yml` like [described here](http://hexo.io/docs/deployment.html).

Additionally you'll have to create an empty `.nojekyll` file at the root of your repository to instruct Github pages not to process you site as a Jekyll site.

`hexo generate --deploy` will then do it well.

Comment: Well its a personal blog, so the generated pages go to master. But should source markdown, templates,  etc live in a different branch or different repo?

Comment: Source code must not live in the same repository, but you can version it in an other branch or another repository.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but it isn't actually stated in the docs as far as I could see.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can build a repo, the constructure is like this:

- repo: xxx.github.io

  - branch: hexo(store your hexo source file)
  - branch: master(store you Blog static pages)

**and set the branch hexo to default branch**.

and now, build the hexo environment, just mkdir a new floder like `D:\hexo`, and `npm install hexo`,`hexo init`,`npm install`,`npm install hexo-deployer-git`

then, connect you local floder to your github repo, git bash here:

```
cd D:\hexo
git init
git remote add origin <your github repo clone url>
git checkout hexo
```

then update the `.gitignore` file, add a ilne:

```
public/
```

then update your `_config.yml`:

```
deploy:
    type: git
    repo: git@github.com:xxx/xxx.github.io.git #your own ssh url, http url is also ok
    branch: master
```

the git bash here:

```
git add .
git commit -m "haha"
git push -f origin hexo
```

last, deploy your Blog:

```
hexo d -g
```